# How to register a service in ASP.NET Core that is created by a factory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting the following error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'IMyRepository' while attempting to activate 'MyController'.

I understand that my application is failing on the dependency injection.

However I'm not sure how to correct this error.

My IMyRepository looks lie this:

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
  public Delete(Guid Id);
  public Get(Guid Id);
  //etc..
}
```

We set the following interface up when we created the unit tests.

```
public IMyRepositoryFactory
{
  IRepository CreateRepository();
}
```

The constructor in my Controller:

```
private readonly IRepository _repo;

public MyController(IRepository repo)
{
   _repo = repo;
}
```

I can pass the factory into the constructor, however that would require me to redo the unit testing modules since they are all passing IRepository to the controller.

```
Ex. (In Startup ConfigureServices)
services.AddTransient<IMyRepositoryFactory, ConcreteRepositoryFactory>();
```

I would prefer to leave the controller constructors and testing classes as is. So is there a way to setup DI in this scenario (Where I am passing the IRepository to the controller)?

EDIT:

```
public class ConcreteRepositoryFactory : IMyRepositoryFactory
{
    public ConcreteRepositoryFactory(string connString);
    public IMyRepository CreateRepository();
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `ConcreteRepositoryFactory ` ?

Comment: Edited post to add

Comment: If you pass services.AddTransient<IMyRepositoryFactory, ConcreteRepositoryFactory>(); you have to extend IMyRepositoryFactory. example public ConcreteRepositoryFactory : IMyRepositoryFactory..

Comment: Since your classes will depend on `IMyRepository` directly, and there seems no reason for them to depend on `IMyRepositoryFactory`, what's the function of that  factory class? Why does it even exist? Why don't you simply register your repository like this: `services.AddTransient<IMyRepository>(c => new MyRepository(conStr));`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to achieve here. Simplistically, you need to bind an implementation of `IMyRepository` if you want to inject `IMyRepository`:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

If you're saying you want to inject the implementation via a factory, you can simply provide a factory to the service registration:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository>(p =>
    p.GetRequiredService<IMyRepositoryFactory>().CreateRepository());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a Transcient `IMyRepositoryFactory` linked to a `ConcreteRepositoryFactory`.

So you cannot inject a IRepository class in your controller, because asp.net Core doesn't know your IRepository class in the transcient injections.

You have to inject instead the `ConcreteRepositoryFactory` class to your controller like this :

`public MyController(ConcreteRepositoryFactory repo)`

And you can store in your readonly property as `IMyRepositoryFactory _repo`.